# Django limit query not working in get_queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I overwrite get_queryset as below:

```
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        qs.order_by('-id').all()[:3]
        print(qs)
        print()

        qs2 = CreditsTransaction.objects.all()[:3]
        print(qs2)
        return qs
```

This is my output:

```
[2023-04-19 08:53:52 +0000] [1178] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1178
<QuerySet [<CreditsTransaction: CreditsTransaction object (623267)>, <CreditsTransaction: CreditsTransaction object (623266)>, <CreditsTransaction: CreditsTransaction object (623265)>, <CreditsTransaction: CreditsTransaction object (623264)>, <CreditsTransaction: CreditsTransaction object (623263)>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>

<QuerySet [<CreditsTransaction: CreditsTransaction object (623267)>, <CreditsTransaction: CreditsTransaction object (623266)>, <CreditsTransaction: CreditsTransaction object (623265)>]>
```

So in `qs.order_by('-id').all()[:3]` the number of results is not limited to 3. Whereas in `CreditsTransaction.objects.all()[:3]` it is. I want to know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a logical error in the code. The line `qs.order_by('-id').all()[:3]` does not get saved back in `qs` variable. So, you print the original `qs`.

You need to do `qs = qs.order_by('-id').all()[:3]` in order to get what you want.

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super().get_queryset(request)
    qs = qs.order_by('-id').all()[:3]
    print(qs)
    print()

    qs2 = CreditsTransaction.objects.all()[:3]
    print(qs2)
    return qs
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super().get_queryset(request)
    qs = qs.order_by('-id')[:3]  # assign the new QuerySet to qs
    print(qs)
    print()

    qs2 = CreditsTransaction.objects.all()[:3]
    print(qs2)
    return qs
```

you are not saving back the queryset